# The method must return a double, but I am getting an error

Tags: java

```
public double accessor(int n)
{
    switch(n)
    {
    case 0:
        return this.a;
        break;
    case 1:
        return this.b;
        break;
    case 2:
        return this.c;
        break;
    case 3:
        return this.d;
        break;
    case 4:
        return this.e;
        break;
    }
}
```

`a,b,c,d,e` are all of type double, but it's telling me that the break statements are unreachable and I must return a type double. I'm new to java so forgive if this sounds stupid

Comment: And what if n is none of the above? You've no default block and Java is right to complain. Also no need for break after return statements since a return statement ends the method.

Comment: What does `accessor(5)` return?

Comment: I would be interested to know your practical usage of this... Using a switch to expose a sequence of encapsulated values seems like you're just missinga collection with an index bounds check. It doesn't loom like it would scale out to more values well.

Answer (score 5):

What if `n` isn't in the range of 0-4?  There is no case for that, and no associated `return` statement.

Have a `default` case that either returns a value (if that value is valid) or throws an `IllegalArgumentException` for it being an invalid value.

Also, although including `break;` statements is normally a good practice, here it is incorrect, because they're unreachable statements.  The `return` statement in a `switch` `case` is as good as a `break` here, because it also prevents "falling through" to the next case.

Comment: Also, `break` after `return` is his first problem concerning "break statements are unreachable"

Comment: @MikeKobit Correct; I was getting to that!

Answer (score 0):

you can't call anything after you call `return`. Just delete de `break` after each `return`, and also make a `default:` case,